# Why am I receiving “Run Time Error 1004 'Application Defined or Object Defined Error'” in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to move the active cell selection up 1 row after deleting the row that info has just been copied from. The error occurs on line 19:

```
Dim row As Integer, col As Integer, MyRow As Integer, MyCol As Integer

Dim str1 As String, str2 As String

row = 2

col = 5

MyRow = ActiveCell.row

MyCol = ActiveCell.Column

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Select

Set curCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, col)

  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

     If ActiveCell = Cells(ActiveCell.row + 1, ActiveCell.Column) Then
        For col = 1 To 15

            Cells(ActiveCell.row, col) = Cells(ActiveCell.row, col) & " | " & Cells(ActiveCell.row + 1 + 1, col)

        Next col

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        Rows(ActiveCell.row).EntireRow.Delete

     End If

     ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select

  Loop
```

I am under the impression that `ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select` will make the selection go up 1 row. Is this not how it's to be done? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Active cell starts at **E2** and is then moved to **E1**.  If **E1** is not empty, the code attempts to move to **E0**, which creates the error.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't realize. Thank you!